# error while accessing nested object properties

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to access properties of a nested object in typescript, ( Angular is used), but i have got : Object is possibly 'undefined'.
this is the code i have written:

```
export interface adress{
city?: string;
neighborhood?: string; 
}


export interface programming{
backend?: string;
frontend?: string;
}

export interface nestedObject{
    firstName?: string;
    lastName?: string;
    completeAdress?: Array<adress>
    fullStackKnowledge?: Array<programming>
}


this.exple=[
      // first user 
      { 
        
        firstName: 'Msaddak',
        lastName: 'Rouabeh',
        
        
        completeAdress: [
          {
            city: 'Gafsa',
            neighborhood: 'Cité Hached Lalla',
          },
          {
            city: 'Monastir',
            neighborhood: 'Skanes',
          }
        ],
        fullStackKnowledge: [
          {
            backend: 'Express js',
            frontend: 'Angular',
          },
          {
            backend: 'Spring boot',
            frontend: 'React js',
          }
        ]
      },
      // Second user
      {
        firstName: 'Houssem',
        lastName: 'Ilahi',
        completeAdress: [
          {
            city: 'Tunis',
            neighborhood: 'Bardoo',
          },
          {
            city: 'Nabeul',
            neighborhood: 'Mrezka',
          }
        ],
        fullStackKnowledge: [
          {
            backend: '.net',
            frontend: 'Vue js',
          },
          {
            backend: 'Express js',
            frontend: 'React js',
          }
        ]
      }


    ]
```

this is my command to access data:  Last name: `{{exple[0].completeAdress[0].city}}</div>`

and this is the error: src/app/nested-objectt/nested-objectt.component.html:6:36 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

Answer (score 1):

Use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
{{exple?.[0]?.completeAdress?.[0]?.city}}
```

> The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does not exist.
> Because at some moment in your app life, some nested property didn't exist yet.